# My basement wall is adjacent to a filled foundation. Is there any point in insulating?

Tags: insulation, basement, foundation

I was planning on putting foam board insulation on my basement walls before finishing. Then I realized that on the other side of the wall isn’t earth, but a poured foundation for my covered porch. Does the concrete provide enough insulation? Is there any point to adding foam board insulation to the interior of this wall?

[image: basement wall]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concrete provides almost no insulating valve. Walls 3 feet below grade are usually figured as being about 55 degrees all year long. Above that 3 feet line they are usually considered to be outside exposed walls. When I finished my basement (near Pittsburgh, Pa.) I insulated all the walls with 1" styrofoam (pink board) and studs. It worked for me

Comment: Thank you! I am near PGH too coincidentally and I have been using 1-inch foam board on the other walls. I'll do the same here